# mvc 3 - ajax.begin form and partial view on httppost

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, partial-views

I have a problem with partialView, cant load parital view after post with Ajax.PostBack. When i click submit button a partialView render as View not as a partial. This is my controller:

```
[HttpPost]
            public PartialViewResult UpdatePersonalData(UserLine user)
            {
                var usr = um.GetUserByLoginMapper(User.Identity.Name);
                ViewBag.Regions = rm.GetAllRegionsMapper().ToList();
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    return PartialView("getLabelsPersonalData", usr);
                }

                return PartialView("getPersonalData", user);
            }

public PartialViewResult getPersonalData()
        {
            ViewBag.Regions = rm.GetAllRegionsMapper().ToList();
            var user = um.GetUserByLoginMapper(User.Identity.Name);
            return PartialView("getPersonalData", user);
        }

        public PartialViewResult getLabelsPersonalData()
        {
            var user = um.GetUserByLoginMapper(User.Identity.Name);
            return PartialView("getLabelsPersonalData", user);
        }
```

**getPersonalData.cshtml** - partialView

```
@model MasterProject.JobForYouFinal.BO.UserLine
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("UpdatePersonalData", new AjaxOptions
    {
        UpdateTargetId = "personalDataContent",
        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
        HttpMethod = "POST"

    }))
    {
        <table style="text-align:center; margin:0 auto;">
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.LabelFor(a => a.PersonalData.Name)</td>
            <td>@Html.EditorFor(a => a.PersonalData.Name)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.LabelFor(a => a.PersonalData.LastName)</td>
            <td>@Html.EditorFor(a => a.PersonalData.LastName)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.LabelFor(a => a.Address.PostCode)</td>
            <td>@Html.EditorFor(a => a.Address.PostCode)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.LabelFor(a => a.PersonalData.KeyWord)</td>
            <td>@Html.EditorFor(a => a.PersonalData.KeyWord)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
                    <td><input id="save" type="submit" value="Zapisz" /></td>
                    <td>@Ajax.ActionLink("Anuluj", "getLabelsPersonalData", new AjaxOptions {
                       UpdateTargetId = "personalDataContent",
                       InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace
                   })</td>

                </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>@Html.ValidationSummary()</td>
        </tr>

        </table>
        }
```

**getLabelPersonalData.cshtml** - partialView

```
@model MasterProject.JobForYouFinal.BO.UserLine

                <table class="myAccountTable">
                 <tr>
                    <td>@Html.LabelFor(a => a.RegistrationDate)</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(a => a.RegistrationDate)</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>@Html.LabelFor(a => a.PersonalData.Name)</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(a => a.PersonalData.Name)</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>@Html.LabelFor(a => a.PersonalData.LastName)</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(a => a.PersonalData.LastName)</td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>@Html.LabelFor(a => a.PersonalData.KeyWord)</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(a => a.PersonalData.KeyWord)</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2"><input id="personalDataButton" type="submit" value="Edytuj" /></td>
                </tr>
                </table>
index.cshtml = glowny widok

<div class="empAccountSectionContainer">
            <div id="personalDataHeader" class="empAccountSectionHeader">Dane personalne</div>
             @using (Ajax.BeginForm("getPersonalData", new AjaxOptions
             {
                 UpdateTargetId = "personalDataContent",
                 InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace

             }))
             {
            <div id="personalDataContent" class="empAccountSectionBody">
                @{Html.RenderPartial("getLabelsPersonalData", Model.User);}

           </div>
             }
        </div>
```

Trying fix this issue with some onSuccess function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function onSuccess() {
        $('#personalDataContent').load('EmployeeAccount/getLabelsPersonalData');
    }
</script>
```

this is my layout imports

```
   <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8" />
            <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>


            <link href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.16/themes/start/jquery-ui.css" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
            <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
            <script str="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/modernizr/modernizr-1.7-development-only.js"></script>
            <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.11/jquery-ui.js"></script>
            <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.templates/beta1/jquery.tmpl.min.js"></script>
            <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.templates/beta1/jquery.tmplPlus.min.js"></script>
            <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/mvc/3.0/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
            <script str="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

            <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/additional-methods.min.js"></script>
            <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
            <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Styles.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

            <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/jquery-ui-1.8.22.custom.css")" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />
            <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/jquery.ui.dialog.css")" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />
            <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/jquery.ui.theme.css")" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        </head>

I had to pust this:

    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/mvc/3.0/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

in my partialView, becouse validation not worked. Now validation working fine, but when model is valid, cant load partial view as partial.

But still no results. Please help.

Comment: Have you referenced the `"~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"` in your view/layout?

Comment: can someone help me? I have all required script references and partialView still dont work

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I had the same problem. I solved it using the code belowe in my view:

```
@{
    Layout = Request.IsAjaxRequest()?null:"~/Views/Shared/Layout.cshtml";
}
```

I don't know if this solution is the best one, but it surely works ;-)